# Jnlp failing to access server

Tags: java, jnlp

I have a java3d applet that uses jnlp to load it. It has been working fine for 3 weeks until today when it said that it couldn't access "http://download.java.net/media/java3d/webstart/release/java3d-latest.jnlp" file. I manually tried to visit the site and all i get is the Error 503 message. SO, is the "download.java.net" site down or do i have a problem with the  JNLP file?

Answer (score 1):

download.java.net is down right now.

Comment: Thanx for the confirmation. By any chance do you know when it will be up? I have been looking for info on the net and I haven't found any.

Comment: Best I've been able to find is a post to an openjdk list saying that there had been a cooling failure in a datacenter and openjdk.java.net and that it and all subdomains won't be back until noon Pacific time today. I assume that goes for download.java.net too. I'm kinda pissed there's not better information available. Dammit, Oracle.